# Booting into Windows 10 usb flickers Windows logo, then reboots

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb, installation

I created a bootable usb from the Windows 10 iso file using woeusb on my linux laptop. I checked, and I can boot into the Windows installer on my thinkpad laptops with no issue. When I try to boot with the usb on my desktop, the screen briefly flickers the Windows logo, then reboots. I'm using a Gigabyte AB350 Gaming motherboard. I've tried with booting options set for UEFI mode and legacy mode, both which result in the same Windows logo flickering, then reboot.

I am completely at a loss with this, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

The Windows 10 version 2004 iso file is broken with my hardware. I used the previous iso version and installation worked.